# HTML5 audio element loads overtop of itself every time new page is loaded via AJAX

Tags: ajax, html, audio

I'm working on a WP template that uses ajax to load pages dynamically. The client wants an audio file to automatically start playing when a user visits the site.

Since the pages are loaded dynamically the audio plays through without interruption nicely. The problem is that when a page is loaded, the audio element reloads and starts playing over itself.

Wondering if anyone has come across this before and might be able to provide some insight into how to have the audio file load once and continue playing as pages are loaded dynamically, but only once.

Any help is, as always, greatly appreciated!

here's my markup:

```
<audio id="player" preload="metadata" autoplay="true" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') ?>/audio/Chillout-Deep.mp3" loop="true">
</audio>
<div id="audio-controls">
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').muted=!document.getElementById('player').muted"><i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i></button>
</div> <!-- #audio-controls -->
```

Answer (score 0):

put your audio outside the dynamic area. pay attention on the button type and the  href, if you use them to load.

```
<body>
<div class="audio"></div>
<div  class="dynamic">
</div>
<button type="button">dynamic-load</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks John, the audio is the first thing added after the body tag. It's loads using the `autoplay="true"` audio tag attribute.